# How to limit the number of posts a user can view based on status

Tags: plugin-development, query-posts, count

I would like to create the subscriber system with the following status for the user: active and pending. So, for the pending status user only can read 3 articles for free. I created using php file and is works, but always failed implemented on the WordPres.

Thanks,

Comment: Please share some more details regarding what things have you tried. If possible, also paste the code that you tried in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you a general idea which may help you. You can try something like below in WordPress -

1) Add a functionality to have `usermeta` as `active` or `pending`

e.g.

```
update_user_meta($user_id, '_user_custom_status', 'active');
```

2) Do not show any post for non logged in user.

3) On login, check for user with `subscriber` role and check its status from `usermeta`

```
$status = get_user_meta($user_id, '_user_custom_status', true);
```

4) Prepare the WP Query to limit the posts for the current user

e.g. you may try as following -

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ); //you may want to display some specific posts or just latest 3 posts or older 3 posts etc, you can change the query according to that
```

Note: 
This is just a general idea based upon which you can implement your code as per your requirements. See if this helps.